# Stackoverflow in RascalMPL

Tags: rascal

I was encountered an exception while testing pretty printer module in rascal:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.StackOverflowError                                  
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowErrorjava.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules
(internal error)
        at $shell$(|main://$shell$|)

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules
/ testing 1/3 error: testAlterV @ |file:///Users/pius/Desktop/Dev/ptlbase/ptlbase/src/lang/spark/prettyprint/Tests.rsc|(444,123,<17,0>,<20,1>)
        Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules
Unexpected (uncaught) exception, closing the REPL: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModulesjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.lang.StackTraceElement$HashedModules

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
```

I only get this issue when increased the number of test. If you need a link to the project I am willing to provide that.

Comment: Hi Pius! Nice to see you again here. Can you post this question as an issue on GitHub with the usethesource/rascal project? Then we will diagnose it because that looks like a bug in the test framework or a bug in the exception handlers.

Comment: Done that, @jurgen

Comment: ok that's nice @pius thanks.